# Order by In MSSQL for below Input. Have to modify below command for output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

INPUT

```
ID  NAME

1   DOLEX-100
2   DoLEX-50
3   DOLEX-200
4   Rolex 
5   apple
```

OUTPUT should be like this

```
ID   NAME
5   Apple
2   DoLEX-50
1   DOLEX-100
3   DOLEX-200
4   Rolex
```

sort by Name. I am using this command but not getting expected output. have to modify the command.

```
 select * from INPUT order by  Name ASC
```

Comment: Are all values in the `Name` column `DOLEX-` followed by digits? (and ignoring case differences). If not, what other patterns might appear and how should the combined sort order by defined?

Comment: not all values are dolex some other values are also there

Comment: Then please *[edit]* your question and add some diversity to your example and, as I previously asked, be sure you clearly describe how the sorting should work.

Comment: In an alphanumeric ordering,  DOLEX-100 and DOLEX-200 come before DOLEX-50.  Is this part of your problem?

Comment: i am using MS SQL

Comment: yes exactly at @  Walter Mitty